# How do you find all divs by class and delete them all?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many divs with a specific class and I want to delete all those divs.  How do you do this using jQuery or javascript?  But, how do you delete **all divs** with a specific class?  Thanks!

code:

```
<div>
  <div class='testa'>test a</div>
  <div class='testb'>test b</div>
  <div class='testc'>test c</div>
  <div class='testa'>test a</div>
  <div class='testb'>test b</div>
  <div class='testc'>test c</div>
  <div class='testa'>test a</div>
</div>
```

How would you delete all div's with the `testa` class?

Comment: Just as a note, your question is being down voted because the answer is extremely easy to find on the internet and your question shows you didn't test your .remove method.

Comment: My fault - remove does work.  Something was overriding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd tried [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove), then you'd know that it works for every element in the matched selection:

```
$('.testa').remove()
```

Comment: to be explicit, `$('div.testa').remove();` (as OP mentioned _divs_ with the class.)

Comment: @BradChristie, sometimes you just have to live on the edge.

Comment: Living on the edge would be `$("*:not(:not(.testa))").remove()`

Comment: Sounds like [enterprise js to me](http://enterprise-js.com/)

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery:

```
$(".testa").remove();
```

Probably a good idea to read the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/) and some tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

its eash with jquery to remove the node.

```
$(".testa").remove();
$(".testb").remove();
$(".testc").remove();
```